# Analyse properties for a photo collection

Tags: windows, photography, exif

I have a large collection of photos stored on my hard drive (currently over 20,000 photos, 100GB). I would like to get some statistics for these, ie properties from the EXIF data.
eg how many photos for each of these properties:

- make/model of camera
- focal length
- aperture
- shutter speed
- ISO
- whether flash is used

Plus filtering on a combination of these. ie what focal length used for particular model of camera, or what aperture for a particular focal length.

It would be useful if the software could display some sort of graphs for these results, or maybe export in a spreadsheet format.

The software should run on Windows 7. And preferably free of charge.

Answer (score 5):

one possible solution. [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

```
exiftool  -r "e:\New Folder"  -Make -Model -focallength -shutterspeed -iso -aperture -flash  -csv >pictures.csv
```

You can then import the data into excel or librecalc and generate graphs or sort the data.

Comment: Worth mentioning: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ and Free, Cross Platform, etc.